# OGLES 2.0 2D Text Rendering using Freetype

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, freetype

Following to link [Rendering fonts with Freetype and OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270822/rendering-fonts-with-freetype-and-opengl/35909441#35909441)

Iam very new to opengles and freetype. 
Can we have another solution for the question in the link? since my project use opengles2 which doesnot contain the symbols GL_R8 and GL_RED.

Do we need to use any GlDraw function after glTexImage2D or glTexImage2D function alone will be enough to display the text using truetype font on the display monitor?
Without using glew, glut functions.

Comment: You can apply the texture to a plane geometry and draw the plane

Comment: Using Vertex shader and fragment shaders, as provided in example 06 of Training Course in TI's OGLES2 Graphic sdk, I did bind the font texture using command glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_uiTexture);
But still Iam not able to get the fonts rendered on the monitor.